# What are the attributes to pass JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I try to use JTextPane to style some text.
I have the following code:

```
try {
        Document d = new DefaultStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        d.insertString(0, "Hello-World", set);
        jTextPane1.setDocument(d);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

How do I get the names of the attributes that can be passed to JTextPane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javax.swing.text.StyleConstants to set the attributes you want eg

```
StyleConstants.setStrikeThrough(set, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Interface AttributeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AttributeSet.html):

> A collection of unique attributes. This is a read-only, immutable interface. An attribute is basically a key and a value assigned to the key. The collection may represent something like a style run, a logical style, etc. These are generally used to describe features that will contribute to some graphical representation such as a font. **The set of possible keys is unbounded and can be anything**. Typically View implementations will respond to attribute definitions and render something to represent the attributes.

Note **The set of possible keys is unbounded and can be anything**